# Swift - Custom setter on property

Tags: swift, setter

I am converting a project in to Swift code and have come across an issue in a setter. My Objective-C code looked like this:

```
- (void)setDocument:(MyDocument *)document
{
    if (![_document isEqual:document]) {
        _document = document;

        [self useDocument];
    }
}
```

and allowed my View Controller to run this each time the document was set (typically in the `prepareForSegue:` method of the presenting View Controller).

I have found the property observers `willSet` and `didSet` but they only work when the property is being updated, not when it’s initialised and updated.

Any ideas? Thanks

UPDATE

after trying get{} and set{} I get the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error

```
var document: UIDocument? {
    get {
        return self.document!
    }
    set {
        self.document = newValue

        useDocument()
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use the property observers. Use get { } and get { }. Check out the Computed Properties section [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override setter in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36440631/how-to-override-setter-in-swift)

Answer (score 54):

You can't use `set` like that because when you call `self.document = newValue` you're just calling the setter again; you've created an infinite loop.

What you have to do instead is create a separate property to actually store the value in:

```
private var _document: UIDocument? = nil
var document: UIDocument? {
    get {
        return self._document
    }
    set {
        self._document = newValue
        useDocument()
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why the compiler asks explicitly to add self into the setter if the result will be an infinite loop. I am the only one here to think it is not an elegant solution to use a private var ? A getter and setter function will make a better job

Comment: Swift is a work in progress. There are many little things like this, which I hope that Apple makes the compiler automatically do the dirty work for you so that you can just concentrate on coding instead of constantly being like "arrrrgh"

Comment: Any updates for swift 3 so far ? left an up-vote anyway.

Comment: This definitively lack of some magic here. Kotlin has the `field` backing field to handle custom getters and setters.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a Swift 3 version

```
var document : UIDocument? {
    didSet {
        useDocument()
    }
}
```