# How to override setter in Swift

Tags: swift, overriding, setter, getter

A Superclass :

```
class MySuperView : UIView{
    var aProperty ;
}
```

A subclass inheritance the super class :

```
class Subclass : MySuperClass{
    // I want to override the aProperty's setter/getter method
}
```

I want to override the superclass's property's setter/getter method ,

how to override this method in Swift ? Please help me , thanks .

Answer (score 70, accepted):

What do you want to do with your custom setter? If you want the class to do something before/after the value is set, you can use `willSet`/`didSet`:

```
class TheSuperClass { 
   var aVar = 0 
} 

class SubClass: TheSuperClass { 
     override var aVar: Int { 
         willSet { 
            print("WillSet aVar to \(newValue) from \(aVar)") 
        } 
        didSet { 
            print("didSet aVar to \(aVar) from \(oldValue)") 
        } 
    } 
} 


let aSub = SubClass()
aSub.aVar = 5
```

> Console Output:
>
> WillSet aVar to 5 from 0
>
> didSet aVar to 5 from 0

If, however, you want to completely change how the setter interacts with the superclass:

```
class SecondSubClass: TheSuperClass { 
     override var aVar: Int { 
        get {
            return super.aVar
        }
        set { 
            print("Would have set aVar to \(newValue) from \(aVar)") 
        } 
    } 
} 

let secondSub = SecondSubClass()
print(secondSub.aVar)
secondSub.aVar = 5
print(secondSub.aVar)
```

> Console output:
>
> 0
>
> Would have set aVar to 5 from 0
>
> 0

Comment: here's the complete description from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html - Overriding Properties

Comment: In the second example, you can also call `super.aVar = newValue` to get the superclass's original behaviour.